# Can I use Extension to end a method name in swift 4.2?

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Can I use Extension to end a method name in swift 4.2? the compiler is suggesting to clip the name, like `registerExtension()` to `register()`, while  `registerMyname()` works fine.

Note: `registerExtension()` & `registerMyname()` are part of my Objective C framework.

Comment: Swift itself does not keep you from using that name, afaik. The way your Obj-C names get "translated" to Swift might interfere, though. Please show the relevant parts of your ObjC @interface.

Answer (score 0):

**Compiler** suggest a name because of in **current version** of **Swift** you're using there's a `method` exists with a new **name** which defined in your **Objective-C** `frameworks`. *By accepting of suggestions it doesn't change anything it works as well as it works before*.